# Is there a R function for creating a 3d cylinder around xyz segment?

Tags: r, 3d, geometry

I'm working in R and I'm trying to have a cylinder around my segment in 3d
the dataset looks like this:

```
x1 = y1 = z1 = x2 = y2 = z2 = runif(10,-1,1)
radius = runif(10,0.1, 0.2)
id = 1:10
data = data.frame(id, x1,y1,z1, x2,y2,z2, radius)
```

I had a solution in 2D when z1 and z2 were equal to 0

```
circus <- seq(-0.95,0.95,0.95/4)
cir <- data.frame(x_cir = rep(circus,2*nrow(data)))%>%
           mutate(y_cir = rep(c(sqrt(1-circus^2),-sqrt(1-circus^2)),nrow(data)),
                  id = sort(rep(id,2*length(circus))))

results <- left_join(cir, data, by = "id")%>%
              mutate(x1 = x_cir*radius+x1,
                     y1 = y_cir*radius+y1,
                     x2 = x_cir*radius+x2,
                     y2 = y_cir*radius+y2)
```

But now, I want to go in 3D. Is there already some function in R to do this kind of transformation ?

Comment: `rgl::cylinder3d` might do what you want.

Comment: It's  simple :-)   3D geometry:  you get the 3-D slope  from your intiial 6 coordinates, and assuming  $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$  is the location of the center of one end of the cylinder, just  create a cylinder of  length defined by your coordinate set, rotate it to align with your line segment, and translate to start at your origin.